# Calculating day difference between 2 date columns where dates are "messy"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query:

```
        SELECT  EmployeeId,
                HireDate,
                TerminationDate
        FROM    dbo.Employment
        WHERE   EmployeeId = 318312
        ORDER BY HireDate,
                TerminationDate;
```

Result:

[image]

I need to get the number of days this person worked. The problem is that the termination date is "messy" ... meaning, I might not get a termination date for every hire date.

So basically I need to put the dates in "order" ... and then figure out how many days the person had of employment.

In this scenario, it goes as follows:

1. Person is hired on 2012-12-19, has no termination date and then was re-hired on 2012-12-27.
2. Person terminates on 2014-03-01 and then is re-hired on 2014-06-05.
3. Person has no termination date after 2014-06-05 so it is assumed he was re-hired on 2014-06-06 rather than 2014-06-05.

How do I go about creating a query that captures the number of EMPLOYMENT days (excluding gaps), in this scenario?

I would be grouping this by EmployeeID as I'm running this for multiple employees.

This problem is really kicking my butt and I need some help.

Comment: Are you supposed to assume the person worked all days between 12/19 and 12/27, since there is no termination date?

Comment: Simple answer is no. So in that case exclude it.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using here?

Comment: I'm using version 2012!

Comment: I don't understand how the termination date can occur before the hire date?

Comment: DavidG... don't ask... it's how we get the data lol... it's messy as I said

Comment: You need to fix the data.  I wouldn't report anything off of a data structure that is filled with NULL values and has hire dates after termination dates.  I might guess the data is coming from Excel and there is an issue importing it.  Fix the data, because you don't even know that those dates align to the person assigned on each row.

Comment: So what dates did this employee actually work? It's not clear.

Comment: You just have to assume the order of the dates... excluding the "range" without a termination .. which in this scenario is just the first row.

Comment: Can you give me the exact date ranges?

Comment: In this scenario, the person worked from 2012-12-27 to 2014-03-01. Then there was a gap between 2014-03-01 and 2014-06-05.

Finally, the person worked from 2014-06-06 to 2015-01-31.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather complex but uses LAG to get the previous row, put that in a CTE and then pick out the data with a CASE:

```
;WITH dataCTE AS
(SELECT EmployeeID,
       LAG(HireDate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY HireDate) PreviousHireDate,
       LAG(TerminationDate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY HireDate) PreviousTerminationDate,
       HireDate, TerminationDate
FROM Employment)

SELECT EmployeeID,
       CASE WHEN PreviousTerminationDate IS NULL THEN PreviousHireDate ELSE HireDate END AS HireDate,
       TerminationDate,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE WHEN PreviousTerminationDate IS NULL THEN PreviousHireDate ELSE HireDate END, TerminationDate) AS NumberOfDays
FROM dataCTE
WHERE TerminationDate IS NOT NULL
```

Example fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f839e/22

Comment: Just beat me to it. Was finishing up my version but I was using `LEAD()`.

Comment: DavidG, just a quick question. If I wanted to take into account the days between the first HireDate (2012-12-19 and 2012-12-27) AS DAYS WORKED, how would I incorporate that into the query?